# How to restrict some properties to modified from Web API in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on .net core Web API project. I have two classes:

```
public class CategoryMasterDto : CommonInfoDto
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryImage { get; set; }
}

public class CommonInfoDto
{
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to restrict users to specify values for certain properties from Web API like CategoryId and all properties of CommonInfoDto as I will specify all these properties from my side before inserting data in the database.

I tried using JsonIgnore using which properties will not be visible in the tools like swagger. But again if the user manually specified those properties, the values will be received on the server-side.

For e.g. if I apply JsonIgnore to CategoryId, it will no be visible in swagger but if the user adds the property CategoryId and pass some value, it will be received on the server-side.

I want to achieve two things:

1. Restrict the users to pass values for certain properties or even if it is passed, those should not be bind to the properties on the server-side during the POST and PUT request.
2. I want to pass all properties when user requests for GET request.

I already have one solution i.e. to create one DTO for GET and another for POST/PUT. Is there any better solution through which I can use the same DTO for both and achieve what I want.?

Comment: You just use a different class for communication than you use internally. Then you can use something like *AutoMapper* to manage using objects of one class to populate the properties of instances of the other class

Answer (score 1):

You need just one DTO class for GET, POST/PUT. And, you could use `AutoMapper` tool to configure mapping from model domain class to DTO class, and back. And then, while configuring mapping from DTO to domain model class, you could ignore certain parameters.

```
CreateMap<CommonInfoDto, CommonInfo>().ForMember(x => x.Guid, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

It means that you would read data from database (your domain model class), pass it to DTO class with all the parameters; but when you would recieve data from from user (DTO class), while saving you will not use its Guid (because it will be ignored during mapping).

Comment: but again, those properties will be visible in the swagger, which I don't want to show, and if I use JsonIgnore for this, those properties wouldn't be serialized when returning response for GET request.

Comment: What is your goal - hide Guid from user, or ignore it while it comes from user? Your domain model will be handled on the server side, so noone could access it.  If you need some Id for DTO class which will not be the same as for domain class because of security or something, then generate such Id while mapping model to DTO - so model's and DTO's Ids will be different, but only you will know on server side how do they match (store that info somewhere). So user will see it, but it will be not "valid".

Comment: Lets take example of categoryid. I want to hide it as well ignore it when received from the user side. But send it in response during the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

As what everybody is suggesting. This can only be Achieve using 2 classes. Input.Model and Domain.Model, then use Automapper to automatically map properties to your actual Domain.Model during input process (POST/PUT) while you return you Domain.Model in your GET endpoints.